# JTabbedPane with close button in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jtabbedpane

I am working with JTabbedPane in netbeans 7 so i need to add close button on every tab. how can i add close button in the tab in netbeans. I just want to make tab like netbeans.

thanks in advance.